# perlcritic: eval "require $module";

Tags: perl, perl-critic

While digging in some old source code I saw the following:

```
my $module = $some{module};
eval "require $module";
die "Bad module\n$@" if $@;
```

while I understand what the code does, it tries "require" a module and die when it is unsuccessful - the perlcritic complains about it

> Expression form of "eval" at line 331, column 13.  See page 161 of
>   PBP.  (Severity: 5)

Unfortunately I havent the PBP book, so wondering what is the correct method of the above...

Also, in the same source found:

```
sub test_repo_file {
    my($self, $repo, $test) = @_;
    my $abspath = repo_abs_path($repo);
    return "eval -$test $abspath";
}
```

Here doesn't understand what solves the "eval", and the perlcritic complains again for the "string eval"...

Can somebody please explain the basic points about the "string eval" and how to write the above correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `perlcritic --verbose '%d\n'` will give you the explanations, too:

> The string form of `eval' is recompiled every time it is executed,
>       whereas the block form is only compiled once. Also, the string form
>       doesn't give compile-time warnings.
>
> ```
>    eval "print $foo";        # not ok
>    eval {print $foo};        # ok
> ```

It's applicable to the first case.

The second case doesn't generate any messages for me. Isn't it rather

```
return eval "-$test $abspath"
```

You can't use block eval here. You should verify that $test really contains what it should

```
$test =~ /^[a-z]$/i
```

and avoid the evaluation of $abspath:

```
eval "-$test \$abspath"
```

If you're OK with that, you can than add

```
## no critic
```

to the end of the line.

Answer (score 6):

Few users should ever have to use `eval EXPR`. Most of the time, it's being used as a template system when it shouldn't (e.g. `s/.../eval($repl)/e`), or it's used to catch exceptions when `eval BLOCK` should have been used.

If there is reason to use it, it's to execute generated code or user-submitted code. Generating code is tricky and error-prone, and errors have security implications. Executing user-submitted code is a major security concern. As such, every use of `eval EXPR` should be carefully reviewed.

It's quite appropriate for `perlcritic` to flag its usage given that virtually every use is an error with major security implications.

---

In your case, the use of `eval EXPR` is suboptimal. I'd use

```perl
my $path = ( $module =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm";
require $path;
```

(Yes, this is portable.)

Better yet, there's [Module::Load](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Load). It's even a core module.

Comment: [Module::Load](https://perldoc.perl.org/Module::Load.txt) has the simple and straightforward code that shows the sorts of things you have to think about, which is basically what ikegami already showed.